# End-Of-Line issues on Dropbox files shared between Mac & Win

Tags: xcode, dropbox, iar, eol

I'm facing some problems when synching text files between Mac and Windows, through Dropbox.

I currently share source code (.c and .h files) between Mac and Windows.
On the Mac side, I'm using Xcode to compile my project, while I'm using IAR on the Windows side.

When compiling my files on Windows, IAR reports the following error:

```
Warning[Pa050]: non-native end of line sequence detected (this diagnostic is only issued once)
```

The problem comes from the End-Of-Line format which is different on Mac and Windows.
I was wondering if one of you already experienced a similar problem, and what could be an elegant solution to solve this issue?

Comment: I doubt there is much you can do about it although these days I would expect both IDEs to accept any type of EOL encoding without complaint.  So I would pursue trying to get IAR to STFU.

Answer (score 2):

If you check in your source code into a version control system like *subversion*, it will ensure that your source code have the correct line ending when you check it out on system. (Provided that you have set the property `svn:eol-style` to `native`.)

Answer (score 2):

In the IAR environment you can suppress the Pa050 warning. Look under Project | Options | C/C++ Compiler | Diagnostics and enter Pa050 in the text area for "Suppress these diagnostics".